# Change single navigation bar color for total app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I have using two UINavigationBar's in my app ,now am applying themes to my app i'm trying to change navigation bar color of the total app using this line of code

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

am getting two navigation bars with black color is there any way to change single navigation bar  color for total app

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `[UINavigationBar appearance]` you can use `[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:...]` to be more specific about which UINavigationBars are changed based on their context.

For example you could create a subclass of `UINavigationController` called `MyNavigationController` (no need to add any behaviour) then do:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MyNavigationController class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Only UINavigationBars that live within your subclass will have their appearance changed.

I've used this idea in an iPad app where I wanted UINavigationBars that appeared within modal FormSheets to look different to other UINavigationBars within the app for example.

Answer (score 0):

To change the over all navigation bar color you can use the method

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

To change the overall font and such you can use something like :

```
-(void) changeNavigationBarStyle{
      [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
      [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],
      UITextAttributeTextColor,
      [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.8f],
      UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
      [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, -1)],
      UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
      [UIFont fontWithName:@"ChalkboardSE-Bold" size:0.0],
      UITextAttributeFont,
      nil]];

    NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary: [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] titleTextAttributesForState:UIControlStateNormal]];
    [attributes setValue:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ChalkboardSE-Bold" size:0.0f] forKey:UITextAttributeFont];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

**EDIT DUE TO COMMENTS**
To change the color (blue in this example) of all UINavigationBars in the application you can call

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

To change the color of one UINavigationBar you can call

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

There is no middle ground where you can say *"Change all UINavigationBar's color except ..."*

Comment: i have 2 navigation bars ,using above 2 navigation bars color is changing i want to change only one navigation bar color that to using appdelegate file

Comment: You are having two navigation bar in one viewController?

Comment: Why?!? That aught to look horrible?!

Comment: it is necessary to use two navigation bars

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
   self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];


    if(isiPhone5)
    {
        self.LoadinFirst = [[LoadingFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoadingFirstView-iPhone5" bundle:nil];
    }
    else {
        self.LoadinFirst = [[LoadingFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoadingFirstView" bundle:nil];
    }
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.LoadinFirst];

    [navigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];

    [navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:192/255.00f green:182/255.00f blue:184/255.00f alpha:1.0f]];
    self.window.rootViewController =navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: i have 2 navigation bars ,using above 2 navigation bars color is changing i want to change only one navigation bar color that to using appdelegate file

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put an image in the navigation bar with the color you want you can use

```
if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)] ) 
    {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"titlebg.png"] ;
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    }
```

else you can easilt set the tint by using

```
[navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:102/255.00f green:182/255.00f blue:114/255.00f alpha:1.0f]];
```

hope this helps.

Comment: i have 2 navigation bars ,using above 2 navigation bars color is changing i want to change only one navigation bar color that to using appdelegate file

Comment: Can you tell me the requirement of two navigation bar